# django-rest-framework-datatables JSON will not Load

Tags: django, datatables

I am using django-rest-framework-datatables and following the directions but can not get to work.

I have followed this:

https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I am getting the warning "DataTables warning: table id=transactions - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

my URLS are in an app called "custom"

```
app_name = 'custom'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'exber', views.ExberViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

    url('^exber/api/', include(router.urls)),
    url('^exber/', views.exber_index, name='exber'),

]
```

my views:

```
class ExberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Exber_transactions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExberSerializer


def exber_index(request):

    return render(request, 'custom/exber/transactions.html)
```

the model:

```
class Exber_transactions ( models.Model ):

    date = models.DateField ( null = True, blank = True )
    desc = models.CharField ( max_length = 100 )
    activity = models.CharField ( max_length = 100 )
    qty = models.DecimalField ( max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 3, default = 0 )
    price = models.DecimalField ( max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0 )
    accrued_int = models.DecimalField ( max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 3, default = 0 )
    amount = models.DecimalField ( max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0 )
```

the serializer:

```
class ExberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField ( read_only = True )

    class Meta:
        model = Exber_transactions
        fields = ('date','desc', 'activity','qty', 'price', 'accrued_int', 'amount')
        datatables_always_serialize = ('id',)
```

and this is the table:

```
<table id="transactions" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" data-server-side="true" data-ajax="custom/api/exber?format=datatables">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-data="date">date</th>
          <th data-data="desc">desc</th>
          <th data-data="activity">activity</th>
          <th data-data="qty">qty</th>
          <th data-data="price">price</th>
          <th data-data="accrued_int">accrued_int</th>
          <th data-data="amount">amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

    </table>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#transactions').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

I suspect it is in a path somewhere?  I have tried many combinations.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the error appears to have been in the serializer not having the "id" field included. I just added this.

```
fields = ('id', 'date','desc', 'activity','qty', 'price', 'accrued_int', 'amount'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have this line in your serializer:

```
datatables_always_serialize = ('id',)
```

But you do not have included the `id` field in your serializer `fields` list.

So, to solve the issue, either remove the `datatables_always_serialize` line or add `id` to your serializer fields.